# Search Form Error 404

Tags: wordpress, search

I get a Search Form Error 404 when i try to search for something on my site my search form code looks like this

```
<form method="get" class="search-form" id="search-form" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
<input type="search" class="search-field" placeholder="<?php _e('Search form', 'fukasawa'); ?>" name="s" id="s" />
<a id="searchsubmit" class="search-button" onclick="document.getElementById('search-form').submit(); return false;"><div class="genericon genericon-search"></div></a>
```

I changed or redirected my homepage site to another url so im not sure if thats the issue for example

Mysite.com is now redirected to mysite.com/front-page

so when i search for something it now adds the /front-page with it.

where as before it was just the Mysite.com and the search

Comment: How did you redirect the homepage, did you change your home url in wordpress settings?

Comment: yeah with the htaacess

Comment: i made the redirection cause my site becomes unresponsive at times and i get a blank page